# jQuery UI tab shows next tab's content when CSS overflow is enabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[image: jQuery UI tabs overflow issue]

I'm using jQquery UI (1.12.1). When I add "overflow-y: scroll;" to the Theme tab shown in the image, the content of the Image tab (Find Images etc) is visible beneath it.

I'm also using the Image Picker plugin (https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/).

Here's my code:

```
<div id=videos_slide_config style='width:100%;height:400px;'>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href='#videos_slide_themes'>Theme</a> </li>
        <li> <a href='#videos_slide_images'>Image</a> </li>
        <li> <a href='#videos_slide_layouts'>Layout</a> </li>
    </ul>

    <div id=videos_slide_themes style='height:320px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;'>
        <select id=videos_slide_theme>{$themes}</select>
    </div>

    <div id=videos_slide_image style='text-align:left;'>
        <p align=center>
            <b>Find Images:</b>
            <input type=text id=videos_images_q width=20> 
            <button class='ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all' onclick='videos_images_search();' title='Find Images'><i class='fa fa-search' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
            <button class='ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all' onclick='videos_imags_upload();' 'title='Upload Images'><i class='fa fa-upload' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id=videos_slide_layout>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use z-index for that theme class.

Comment: Check this line <button class='ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all' onclick='videos_imags_upload();' 'title='Upload Images'><i class='fa fa-upload' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>  You have a extra single quote. Remove that it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My id attributes were wrong. Fixed.